# How to import colorPickerDialog library in android studio

Tags: android, colors, dialog, picker

I everyone

I downloaded this library to use it in my application :
https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

unfortunally, I don't know how to "install" it on android studio and add it in my application in a preferenceActivity

Anyone can help me?
thanks

Comment: Can you please describe what you have tried?

Comment: I tried to do this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCKWIDGULfY
But it seems that the library is not recognized by android studio

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just import it like other libraries so that the source is in the "src" folder and then add the layout to the preferences file.

preferences xml file.

```
    <yuku.ambilwarna.widget.AmbilWarnaPreference
            android:key="your_preference_key"
            android:defaultValue="0xff6699cc" 
            android:title="Pick a color" />
```

Comment: I tried to import all necessary files (java class, layout, drawable) into my solution but I have this error :

E/ActivityThread(  515): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tidus.AmbilWarnaPreference" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tidus.Ephemeridroid-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.tidus.Ephemeridroid-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

I juste rename the package of each class

Comment: So it's ok. I forgot to rename some reference, everything works great. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this color picker: [github.com/chiralcode/Android-Color-Picker](https://github.com/chiralcode/Android-Color-Picker) and simply copy two java files directly to your project.